# Simple HTML Dom - find text after div

Tags: php, dom

I need to extract the text in After divs using Simple HTML Dom PHP library. I have tried next_sibling() to get text but it's dont work.

```
<div class="one">one<div>
<div class="data">mydata</div>
get this text
<div class="two">two</div>
```

My code:

```
$res = $div->find('div[class="data]',0);
if($res->plaintext == 'mydata'){
    echo $res->next_sibling()->plaintext  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

It seems you want to parse an HTML using `DOMDocument` method. If that might be the case, you might instantiate a new object, maybe similar to:

```
$dir = '<div class="one">one<div>
<div class="data">mydata</div>
get this text
<div class="two">two</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($dir);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$res = $xpath->document->documentElement->textContent;

$textNodes = explode(PHP_EOL, $res);
foreach ($textNodes as $key => $text) {
    if ($text == 'mydata') {
        echo $textNodes[$key + 1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Then, you can do the rest of anything that you wish to do with document.

#### Output:

```
get this text
```

#### Document

If you `var_dump($xpath->document->documentElement);`, you can find out how you might want to use attributes of documentElement object:

```
twoobject(DOMElement)#3 (18) {
  ["tagName"]=>
  string(4) "html"
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(4) "html"
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  string(20) "one
mydata
two
three"
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(1)
  ["parentNode"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["nextSibling"]=>
  NULL
  ["attributes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=>
  string(4) "html"
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(20) "one
mydata
two
three"
}
```

Comment: Hi Emma. Thanks for your reply, 
i'am using PHP Simple HTML Dom library to get text "**get this text**" from after <div class="data">mydata</div>

Answer (score -1):

It's look you need to change your html content with `Simple_html_dom`.

I find one solution for you that return `get this text`.

```
$res = $html->find('div[class="data"]',0);
    if($res->plaintext == 'mydata'){
        $res->parent()->first_child()->outertext ='';
        $res->parent()->last_child()->outertext ='';
        echo $res->parent()->innertext;
    }
```

after i find `div` with `class='data'` i changed the html content and remove first and last element , so the plain text that you want remains.

Comment: Thanks Mohsen Shakibafar, this is also a solution