# Finding Child Elements of Div containing specific string

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to find all child elements of a div that contains a specific string. For example, in the following HTML content, I need to find all child elements of the "Trees" div, including the `<div>Trees` pair. There are no classes or IDs associated with each div, so I can't search for IDs or classes.

I tried the following code, using an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989111/1466973 , but the expected content was not returned by the function.

```
<?php
$html_text = "
<html>
<div>Grass
    <div>Good grass
        <div>Grass 1</div>
        <div>Grass 2</div>
        <div>Grass 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>Weeds
        <div>Weeds 2</div>
        <div>Weeds 3</div>
        <div>Weeds 4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>Trees
    <div>Good Trees
        <div>Tree 1</div>
        <div>Tree 2</div>
        <div>Tree 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>Tall Trees
        <div>Tree 11</div>
        <div>Tree 12</div>
        <div>Tree 13</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>Fruit
    <div>Red
        <div>Fruit 1</div>
        <div>Fruit 2</div>
        <div>Fruit 31</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html> ";

echo find_content($html_text);  // this should be only the content of the div containing "Trees"

// tried this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989111/1466973 , didn't work
function find_trees($html_text = "") {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html_text);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $res = $xpath->document->documentElement->textContent;

    $textNodes = explode(PHP_EOL, $res);
    $trees_html = "";
    foreach ($textNodes as $key => $text) {
        if ($text == 'Trees') {
            $trees_html .= $textNodes[$key + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
    "end of this function<br>";
 return $trees_html;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Edited the code in the question to indicate desired extracted data - the 2nd block of HMTL, the 'trees' section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way and see if it works:

Edited:

Since you are using `DOMDocument` to parse XML, you might as well use its xpath support to specify, succinctly, what your are looking for:

```
 $target = $xpath->query("//div[contains(.,'Trees')]");
```

That's it. The rest is just a method to output to screen the string representation, in XML format, of what you have located:

```
 $trees = $target[0]->ownerDocument->saveXML($target[0]);
    echo $trees;
```

Comment: Your last code block gives errors:

"Notice: Trying to get property 'ownerDocument' of non-object" and "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function saveXML() on null"

Comment: @RickHellewell [take a look here.](https://3v4l.org/TRls9)